Animal Inheritance Puzzle
The animal inheritance puzzle can be formulated as finding naturals $a,b,c$ such that
$$\frac1a + \frac1b + \frac1c + \frac1{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)} = 1$$
The numerator of the rightmost addend is the number of animals that are borrowed
to provide for exact divisions; $1$ in the typical case being considered here.  A
larger lcm is desirable since that leads to a more precise distribution of the
units of inheritance.  For example, if the inheritance is $41$ animals and the
fractions to be distributed are $\frac12$, $\frac13$, and $\frac17$, then the inheritance
distribution represents $97.6\%$ of the total and there is only $2.4\%$ remaining that
is consumed in making whole numbers of animals to be distributed.
A simple search program provides the following 7 solutions:

    a   b   c   lcm     1/a + 1/b + 1/c

    2   3   7   42      0.9762
    2   3   8   24      0.9583
    2   3   9   18      0.9444
    2   3   12  12      0.9167
    2   4   5   20      0.9500
    2   4   6   12      0.9167
    2   4   8   8       0.8750

Can it be proven that no other solutions exist?  If other solutions exist, can
it be shown that their lcm is always 1 more than a prime?  The latter is
equivalent to the total inheritance $\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)$ being prime.

Nice that of always $1$ more than a prime

To clarify, I'm assuming a,b,c are distinct (e.g., no inheritor gets the same as another).  There are another 5 solutions if they are not distinct, one of which (2,5,5) violates the prime rule.

I've posted an answer about why those are the only solutions. It's nice that the LCMs are all one more than a prime, but don't read too much into it - there are only seven solutions, and six distinct LCMs. If you try solving the problem with a different number of terms, this doesn't hold - eg $(a,b,c,d)=(2,4,8,16)$ whose LCM is $16$. (One thing that does hold in general as you change the number of terms is that $2,4,8,\ldots$ is always a solution.)

The Wikipedia article you linked mentions that for your specific variation, there are exactly seven solutions.

Short answer: you found all the solutions. Long answer...
Since you're looking for $a,b,c$ distinct, let's take $a<b<c$, and write $L=\text{lcm}(a,b,c)$. We'll try to find some bounds.
From $a<b<c$, we have $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}<\frac{3}{a}$.
$L$ is a multiple of $a$, but also of $c$; therefore $L>a$ and in fact, $L\ge 2a$, so $\frac{1}{L}\le \frac{1}{2a}$.
Putting these together,
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{L}<\frac{3}{a}+\frac{1}{2a}=\frac{7}{2a}$$
So $\frac{7}{2a}>1$; ie $a<\frac72$. Clearly $a>1$, so $a=2$ or $a=3$.
We can repeat this process. If $a=2$, the equation becomes
$$\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(2,b,c)}=\frac12$$
As before, $\text{lcm}(2,b,c)\ge 2b$, so
$$\frac12=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(2,b,c)}<\frac{5}{2b}$$
and so $2<b<5$, ie $b$ is $3$ or $4$.
If $b=3$,
$$\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(6,c)}=\frac16$$
Now, $\text{lcm}(6,c)\in \{c,2c,3c,6c\}$, and it's easy enough to solve this equation for $c$ in each case and find the only integer solutions are $c\in\{7,8,9,12\}$.
If $a=2$ and $b=4$, we have
$$\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(4,c)}=\frac14$$
and we find $c\in\{5,6,8\}$.
This deals with $a=2$.

The $a=3$ case is simpler. Since $3<b<c$, we have $b\ge4$ and $c\ge5$ and $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)>5$, so
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\text{lcm}(a,b,c)<\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac15<1$$
so there are no other solutions.

COMMENT. -Here a graphical proof of non-existence of other solutions than the seven given by the OP (these solutions can easily be calculated this way instead of using a calculator). It is a comment, I am not looking for reputation points, I like this solution and I trust that others may like it.
One has $1\lt a\lt b\lt c$ and because of the $l.c.m.$ of $(a,b,c)$ we have four cases:
$(1)$ $\space\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c+\dfrac{1}{abc}=1\iff a=\dfrac{bc+1}{bc-b-c} \text {with solution } (a,b,c)=(2,3,7)$
$(2)$ $\space\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c+\dfrac{1}{bc}=1\iff a=\dfrac{bc}{bc-b-c-1}\text {with solutions } (a,b,c)=(2,3,8),(2,4,5)$
$(3)$ $\space\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c+\dfrac{1}{ac}=1\iff a=\dfrac{b(c+1)}{bc-b-c}\text {with solutions } (a,b,c)=(2,3,9),(2,4,6)$
$(4)$ $\space\dfrac 1a+\dfrac 1b+\dfrac 1c+\dfrac{1}{c}=1\iff a=\dfrac{bc}{bc-2b-c}\text {with solutions } (a,b,c)=(2,3,12),(2,4,8)$
In all the figures $1,2,3,4$, when $a=2$ there are non-empty intersection of the corresponding curve with the shadow región formed by points $(b,c)$ with $b\ge3$ and $c\ge4$ so there are possibilities of solution as in fact occurs. But when $a=3$ the four intersections are empty so is not posible to exist solutions. (An so is, a fortiori, when $a\gt3$ because in these cases the curves on $b,c$ move closer to the origin while the shadod regions move away in the opposite direction).





This is a nice idea but there are more possibilities for the LCM than the four you've considered. You've said $\text{lcm}(a,b,c)\in {abc,bc,ac,c}$. What about $(a,b,c)=(6,10,15)$?

@Chris Lewis:   You are right. I suppose the same apply to the equality $a=\dfrac{bcL}{L(bc-b-c)-bc}$ whatever the l.c.m. $L$ be..I have stopped to look at this question. Maybe you are interested to examine the literal case corresponding to your example. I agree completely with you in that this way is nice. Regards.

COMMENT
The problem can be generalized to a benefactor with $n \ge 2$ heirs/heiresses
having (Egyptian) inheritance fractions $1/x_1,...,1/x_n$, where the $x_i$ are
naturals.  Here we are no longer assuming the $x_i$ are distinct, but the sum of
the preceding fraction list must be less than 1.  We also assume that $m$ is the
whole number of "borrowed" or "consumed" animals, so that
$$
 1/x_1 + ... + 1/x_n + m/\text{lcm}(x_1,...,x_n) = 1
$$
The number of animals to start with is $\text{lcm}(x_1,...,x_n) - m$.  Typically, $m$ is small, such as 1 in the standard form of the puzzle or possibly 2 in other variants.  Wolog, we can
take $2 \le x_1 \le ... \le x_n$ and solve iteratively as in the accepted answer above,
with the objective of determining minimum and maximum values that can be
taken by each $x_i$ in terms of the preceding variables.  In each case,
$\text{lcm}(x_1,...,x_n) \ge x_i$, so the first iteration produces
$$
 1/x_1 + ... + 1/x_n \le n/x_1  \text{ and }  m/\text{lcm}(x_1,...,x_n) \le m/x_1,
$$
so
$$
 1 \le (n + m)/x_1,
$$
from which we have
$$
 2 \le x_1 \le n + m
$$
In a similar way, the second iteration produces
$$
 1/x_2 + ... + 1/x_n \le (n - 1)/x_2 \text{ and } m/\text{lcm}(x_1,...,x_n) \le m/x_2,
$$
so
$$
 x_1 \le x_2 \le \dfrac {n + m - 1} {1 - 1/x_1}
$$
and in general, the ith iteration results in
$$
 x_{i-1} \le x_i \le \dfrac {n + m - i + 1} {1 - 1/x_1 - ... - 1/x_{i-1}} \equiv R_i, 2 \le i \le n,
$$
subject to the denominator being positive.  The integer part of $R_i$ is used as
the upper bound for the natural $x_i$.  $R_i$ can be defined recursively as
$$
 R_i = \dfrac {n + m - i + 1} {(n + m - i + 2)/R_{i-1} - 1/x_{i-1}}, R_1 = n + m
$$
The lcm $L_i$ of $x_1,...,x_i$ can also be defined recursively as
$$
 L_i = \text{lcm}(L_{i-1},x_i), L_1 = x_1
$$
A search program can be used to check these combinations and find the valid
ones.  After implementing nested loops for $x_1,...,x_n$, a solution is one that
satisfies
$$
 L_n/x_n + m = (m + 1)L_n/R_n
$$
Some performance figures are:

    Solutions/Searched

    n   m=1         m=2

    2   3/4         2/8
    3   12/24       10/57
    4   97/454      54/961
    5   1568/43409  757/81483

